# How do I get the mangled name of a NamedDecl in Clang?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, name-mangling

I am using Clang to parse some C++ code. I would like to print the name and mangled name for every `FunctionDecl` that I encounter.

I can print the function name fairly easily by adding this to my `RecursiveASTVisitor`:

```
bool VisitFunctionDecl(FunctionDecl* f) {

  auto declName = f->getNameInfo().getName();
  auto functionName = declName.getAsString();

  std::cout << functionName << std::endl;

  return true;
}
```

How can I also print the mangled name?

---

Working code I produced after following Sebastian's pointers:

```
const auto getMangledName = [&](FunctionDecl* decl) {

  auto mangleContext = context.createMangleContext();

  if (!mangleContext->shouldMangleDeclName(decl)) {
    return decl->getNameInfo().getName().getAsString();
  }

  std::string mangledName;
  llvm::raw_string_ostream ostream(mangledName);

  mangleContext->mangleName(decl, ostream);

  ostream.flush();

  delete mangleContext;

  return mangledName;
};
```

Comment: I know it's been ages, but your working code leaks the mangle context if the early return is taken. You should capture it in a smart pointer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The mangled name is not part of the AST, since it depends on the ABI. To get a mangled name, you need to create an appropriate `clang::MangleContext` subclass (from `clang/AST/Mangle.h`). Currently there's `MicrosoftMangleContext` for the Visual Studio-compatible mangling, and `ItaniumMangleContext` for the common C++ ABI mangling.

In the most simple version, you then just call `mangleName`, passing in a `NamedDecl` whose name you want to mangle, and a `raw_ostream` that the mangled name is written to.

For more complex things like lambdas, you may also have to call `startNewFunction` at appropriate points, since their mangling depends on what function they are in.

Comment: Also, there are a lot of small details here and there: several variants for constructors and destructors, thunks for virtual methods.  clang::index::CodegenNameGenerator might be used as a reference here.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a safer solution.

Let's take a look at how `JSONNodeDumper` works:

> llvm-project-llvmorg-16.0.4/clang/lib/AST/JSONNodeDumper.cpp

```cpp
void JSONNodeDumper::VisitNamedDecl(const NamedDecl *ND) {
  if (ND && ND->getDeclName()) {
    JOS.attribute("name", ND->getNameAsString());
    // FIXME: There are likely other contexts in which it makes no sense to ask
    // for a mangled name.
    if (isa<RequiresExprBodyDecl>(ND->getDeclContext()))
      return;

    // Mangled names are not meaningful for locals, and may not be well-defined
    // in the case of VLAs.
    auto *VD = dyn_cast<VarDecl>(ND);
    if (VD && VD->hasLocalStorage())
      return;

    std::string MangledName = ASTNameGen.getName(ND);
    if (!MangledName.empty())
      JOS.attribute("mangledName", MangledName);
  }
}
```

`JSONNodeDumper` leverages `ASTNameGenerator::getName` to mangle a `NamedDecl`.

If you read the source code of `ASTNameGenerator::getName`, you will find that it ultimately mangles the name through `MangleContext::mangleName`. Before calling `MangleContext::mangleName`, `ASTNameGenerator::getName` will perform many checks to prevent exceptions.

Creating an `ASTNameGenerator` object is very simple, you just need to pass your `ASTContext` to its constructor:

```cpp
explicit ASTNameGenerator(ASTContext &Ctx);
```

> Not sure how to obtain `ASTContext`? Start by reviewing these official tutorials:
> https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Tooling.html
> https://clang.llvm.org/docs/RAVFrontendAction.html

The final code is as follows:

```cpp
#include "clang/AST/Mangle.h"

std::string getMangledName(const NamedDecl* decl) {
    if (decl && decl->getDeclName()) {
        if (isa<RequiresExprBodyDecl>(decl->getDeclContext()))
            return "";

        auto *varDecl = dyn_cast<VarDecl>(decl);
        if (varDecl && varDecl->hasLocalStorage())
            return "";

        // astNameGenerator is your ASTNameGenerator object
        return astNameGenerator.getName(decl);
    }
    return "";
}
```